# Safer way of performing SUDO from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sudo

hi i am performing **SUDO** from shell script and taking instruction from hereDOC. But i want to know i am doing it correct or in safer way or not . It sometime locks my account(when i tried to change path ) i don't know why.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set the STRING variable
path=/u/siebel/abcdef/sie/sieb/
echo abcd | sudo -S /usr/bin/su - abcdef << EOF
crontab -l > cronbackup1.txt
#ls -lrt
cd "$path"
ls -lrt
EOF
```

Above script just locked my account . But when i executed it without `cd` it worked fine . This time it prompts me wrong password 3 times on its own as i do `./testing.sh` and get locked can some one explain me why it runs 3 times there is no loop in script though ?

This what i get after setting cd "$path".

```
Password: Sorry, try again.
Password: Sorry, try again.
Password: Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

For same password crontab worked fine.

Comment: What message do you get? I'm pretty sure it won't say "Your account has been locked because...". It asks for the password 3 only if you enter the wrong password because that's the behavior of sudo. Try running `sudo echo test`.

Comment: @NieDzejkob updated answer

Comment: `3 incorrect password attempts` means `3 incorrect password attempts`, not `intruder alert`. Stop reading what isn't written.

Comment: @NieDzejkob but it only happens when i try to change path not else way and why it runs 3 times.If i write many other commands it is fine with same password.

Comment: @NieDzejkob now it is not working for anything but password is correct i have confirmed that.

Comment: What user is the password you are using for?

Comment: @NieDzejkob its my userid password.

Comment: You would be better off creating the script and then setting up user with password less sudo to that script. That way, there is no need to su at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
somecmd | cmd << EOF
...
EOF
```

The `stdin` of `cmd` will be the content of the here-document,
and whatever is coming from the pipeline will not be read.
The `stdout` of `somecmd` will be closed without reading anything from it.

So what happens in your example is that `sudo` tries to read the password from the here-document, instead of the `echo` that you tried to pipe to it.

In other words, you cannot supply the password to `sudo` and at the same time pass a here-document to its shell.

What you can do is separate these two actions,
by taking advantage of the timeout option of `sudo`.
That is, once you successfully used `sudo`,
it remembers your authenticated state for a while,
and subsequent calls to `sudo` will not ask for the password again.

```
echo abcd | sudo -S true
sudo /usr/bin/su - abcdef << EOF
crontab -l > cronbackup1.txt
#ls -lrt
cd "$path"
ls -lrt
EOF
```

**But I urge you not to do this.**
Passing your password in clear text in the shell,
and especially in a script is very poor security.
It would be better to create a dedicated script to perform the action you need with the other user account and configure `sudoers` appropriately.

Comment: thanks janos for good explanation is there any requirement to use BASH above?

Comment: @TusharSharma I don't understand your comment. In any case there are no Bash requirements to talk about in the context of your question and this answer.

Comment: It's OK Janos your answer helped me solved my issue thanks .